# using if and else statement in javascript to display image (if image doesn't exists display other image)

Tags: javascript, django

Hello is it possible to use django template language and javascript together such as this way:

```
                {% if post.main_image %}
<img src="{{post.get_image_url}}"  class="img-rounded" alt="☺" height="75" width="75"/>
  {% elif post.url %}
  {% video post.url as my_video %}
        <img src="{{ my_video.thumbnail }}" id="myThumb" class="img-rounded" alt="☺" height="75" width="75"/>
{% endvideo %}
{% else %}
<img src="{{post.thumbnail}}"  class="img-rounded" alt="☺" height="75" width="75"/>
{% endif %}



<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var i = $('mythumb');   // using an id  <img id='mythumb'.....
    if( i.width === 0 ) i.src='<img src="{{post.image}}"  class="img-rounded" alt="☺ EBAGU" height="75" width="75"/>';
}


</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`img` doesn't have a length. You can test `img.width`.

`$(document).ready(function() {
    var i = $('mythumb');   // using an id  <img id='mythumb'.....
    if( i.width === 0 ) i.src='y';
}`

Using the same image will use the right place.

Comment: I have edited with what I tried, do you mind taking a look at?

Comment: `
    var i = $('myThumb'); //!!
    if( i.width === 0 ) i.src='{{post.image}}';
`

Comment: but I want to set post.image to be like that in css

Comment: it's an image so there has to be img tag between

Comment: i is the image tag with id='myThumb'. If you set i.src=url (try in browserconsole) this image will be replaced by another. There is no need for another img tag.

Comment: by the way, javascript only 'sees' one of your 3 img-tags, because of the {% if  and else only one is rendered and accessible for javascript

Comment: are winixxee and mike braa the same?

Try it in a browser. (Chrome)  
F12 - Console.
i = document.getElementById('myThumb')  -> should not be "undefined"  and then  i.src='anypictureURL'.  The picture should be replaced. If this is what you want... to replace a picture

Comment: ay yes for post.thumbnail I get the image, but when I don't have post.thumbnail I get null. I need to get post.image instead of null

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108912/discussion-between-mike-braa-and-holger).